# set jquery validation label on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Morning, I wanna call the label when a function onkeyup return false, for example.
I set jquery validator, and i set a rule clled

```
e-mail: {
email:true,
required:true
}
```

but I have another function that validate the email and return false if it is not correct and true if the opposite.

```
function emailvalidate(email_string){
[regex test emailstring] 
return true or false //(and show label of jqueryvalidator)
}
```

now, when I write an invalid email Jquery validator shows a label saying **`email wrong`** but I need also that on keyup or on focus other field it will test the email form value with my function `emailvalidate()` and if it returns false it will show the message of the jquery validator plugin.
sth like

```
$("#email-field").on("keyup",emailvalidate($("#email-field").val()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i dont have any idea about your plugin well if you will you can use this js validation code to validate

```
function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    return (false)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#email-field").on("keyup",function(e){
    var mail = $("#email-field").val();
    var result = ValidateEmail(mail);
    if(result == true){
        //do something here
    }else{
        //do something here
    }
    return result;
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Comment: i'm using [JqueryValidation ](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin, it is simple, i want to show the label error of jquery when my function detect an incorrect email.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my problem, just added a new method to my existing validator, with the function.

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("correoval", function(emailAddress) {
                    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
                    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
                }, "Ingrese una dirección de correo válida");
```

An then the rules for jQueryValidator

```
$("#MyForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    corrA: {
                        email: true,
                        required: true,
                        correoval:true //this was the method that I added
                    }
```